# How to resolve image( android.R) issue and R.styleable in android?

Tags: android, image

I really tried to use coverflow and it makes me really frustrated. I don't know where to start but am trying to figure with my a little knowledge. But I was encountering a big barrier here.
Although my images1~6 are png, it says image cannot be resolved. When I delete import android.R and retype like import at.hellohello.samples.R, it has a red underline. When there is nothing in the import section and I clicked command+shift+o, automatically android.R appeared. I'm stucked in this stage for 1 week...

```
package at.hellohello.samples;

import android.R;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ImageView;


public class FancyCoverFlowSampleAdapter extends FancyCoverFlowAdapter {

    // =============================================================================
    // Private members
    // =============================================================================

    private int[] images = {R.drawable.image1, R.drawable.image2, R.drawable.image3, R.drawable.image4, R.drawable.image5, R.drawable.image6,};
..
```

Please help me

And in other code, R.styleable cannot be resolved. I really want to know what it is and solve it :(
I'm looking forward to hearing any opinions!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm going to go out on a limb here and assume that all of your resources R.drawable, R.layout, R.anything are unresolved. This is likely due to the R.java file not generating correctly. Look in gen/yourapppackage to find R.java. If it's not there, you've got a problem. If it is there, open it up and take a look to see if your resources are listed in there. If they are there and not being recognized, try doing a clean build (in Eclipse Project > Clean...). If R.java does not regenerate then you most likely have an issue in your XML somewhere (probably in a layout file). Fix your XML problem and then clean again and you should be fine.

Note that you should not need to import android.R.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I followed your instruction and all R related issues are gone!! :)

Answer (score 1):

I guess that this line is not what you want:

```
import android.R;
```

If you have the issue of unresolved `R` when you remove that, think about this:

R is a generated class, it should be available. If it isn't, do not auto-import any R you can find, but look at the problems in your code: something is stopping R from being generated. This can be a syntax error, or some other unresolved problem. It can be anything, so it's a bit too broad to try and cover all that here. Check out your 'problems' tab in your IDE (Eclipse?) if you use that.

Comment: You're right! I erased most suspicious part and started from the beginning with the intermediate checking.Now R file is not auto-generated. Thanks a lot!!